# Why does window.onload only work as expected on the first array value and I have to reload the page for additional array values?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to hide some content based on whether the page name is included in an array, but can only get it to work properly on the first item in the array.

I have been working with the below code, and have had some degree of success.

```
window.onload = function () {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var string_contains = ['careers', 'accessibility', 'privacy', 'cookie-policy', 'legal', 'terms-of-business', 'sitemap',  'search'];

  for(var i =0;i < string_contains.length; i++){
    if(url.indexOf(string_contains[i]) != -1) {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("embeddedServiceHelpButton");
      for(var a = 0;a<x.length;a++) {
        x[a].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(a);
}
```

I expect my content with the class of `embeddedServiceHelpButton` to be hidden for all pages named in the array.

However, it only works fine on the first item in the array each time, but not for the subsequent items in the array unless I reload the page again, which is less than ideal.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If your URL contains at least one of those strings, then all the buttons with that class on the page will be hidden. Once that's happened for the first matching string, nothing will change.

Comment: Note that the window can only have one URL at a time.

Comment: @Pointy What doesn't make sense, that it's not working as expected?

Comment: No, your expectations don't make sense. Even if the page URL matches several of those strings, the only thing that can possibly happen is for all the elements with class "embeddedServiceHelpButton" to  be hidden. Once they're hidden, hiding them again won't change anything.

Comment: JavaScript code runs on a page-by-page basis. What you do to the DOM on one page does not affect any subsequently-loaded page; that's simply not how things work.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it only works fine on the first item in the array each time, but not for the subsequent items in the array unless I reload the page again"_? If you load a page and the buttons are hidden as expected, you don't need to hide buttons again until the next page load, right?

Comment: @Pointy That's just it, they are only being hidden on the first array value, "careers".  When I navigate to another page named in the array, it displays the button, unless I reload the page.

Comment: So if you navigate to something like _"example.com/privacy"_ the buttons are not hidden?

Comment: @benvc Yes, unless I click to refresh the browser.

Comment: Are those buttons being created with JavaScript?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "navigate to another page"?  Simple old-school page-to-page navigation involves a complete reload of the window. What happened in the previous page has absolutely no effect on the subsequent page. If you've got some sort of single-page framework, then everything *still* makes sense because when you update the DOM with new content that content won't be affected by things you've done to the DOM previously.

Comment: Basically there's no getting around the fact that you'll need to re-run that code on every page change no matter what that means for your application.

Comment: @benvc Yes, they're a from a thrid party script.

Comment: @Pointy The code is being run every time a new page is loading, but it doesn't seem to pick up on any values other than the first one without a manual page reload.

Comment: Well with out more context, like what it is exactly that you mean by "new page is loading", it's impossible to help further. The code you posted, if included on what most people mean by "a page", will hide the buttons when the browser signals the page that it's finished loading. If your buttons are created by some script after that point, then your code won't affect them.

Comment: As noted by @Pointy, it may be that the buttons have not yet been created when the windows `load` event fires. Not really possible to know what is happening without more context on how and when the button html is created.

Comment: By "new page is loading" (should have read - "new page is loaded"), I meant navigating to another page on the site.  For example a page where the name is an array value.

Comment: Thank you both for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to discern exactly what's going on, but you might have better luck with a CSS-based solution. What you'll need is a modification to the code you posted plus a `<style>` element with a CSS rule:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var string_contains = ['careers', 'accessibility', 'privacy', 'cookie-policy', 'legal', 'terms-of-business', 'sitemap',  'search'];

  for(var i =0;i < string_contains.length; i++){
    if(url.indexOf(string_contains[i]) != -1) {
      document.body.classList.add("hide-service-buttons");
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(a);
}
```

CSS rule:

```
<style>
  body.hide-service-buttons .embeddedServiceHelpButton {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

With that, even if the buttons are added long after the page loads, the buttons won't be shown. (Probably; there might be conflicting CSS rules, but ultimately this approach should be successful.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  Worked a treat.